# High(er) level frameworks that wrap Tkinter/ttk

Tags: python, user-interface, frameworks, tkinter, ttk

Curious if there are any higher level frameworks that attempt to wrap Tkinter? For example, wxPython is wrapped by the Dabo framework (http://dabodev.com/) and PythonCard.

Motivation: We've recently moved to Python 2.7 (Windows) and are very impressed with the new ttk (Tile) support which allows one to build professional quality, platform native GUI's using the built-in Tkinter framework. In the past we would have used wxPython to create simple GUI interfaces for our command line utilities, but we're re-thinking this strategy in favor of using Tkinter/ttk for these use cases.

We're new to Tkinter (coming from wxPython) and while Tkinter/ttk seem to be simple to use, there seems to be a lot of repeated boilerplate code that we're writing. Before we try to wrap up some of our code in a home made set of classes, I want to make sure that we're not re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

Probably a little bit late for you. But I've just released a tkinter framework in beta called **tKroopy**. Which aims to provide a means for switching between dialogs and provide some higher level widgets, like easily displaying tabulated data.

It was designed for building lots of small to medium applications and grouping them together in a single application, but there is no reason why you couldn't use it to build a single large scale application too.

https://github.com/tKroopy/tkroopy

Answer (score 2):

The only one I knew about seems quite stale, [Python megawidgets](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/).

You can find a list of others on the [Tkinter wiki](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/TixVsPmwVsBWidgets).

Answer (score 2):

tkRAD supports python 2 and 3 and looks mature

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tkRAD/1.6.5